# Slurm multiple job arrays on a single GPU?

Tags: jobs, slurm, job-scheduling

I want to ask if it is possible to run multiple jobs (via job-array) on a single GPU (i.e. sharing the GPU). I am asking because each task only takes up 3GB of GPU RAM, and hence if it would be better if I could run 8 python scripts on a single GPU?

I tried doing something like :

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name parallel_finetune  #job name을 다르게 하기 위해서
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --nodelist=node3 #used node4
#SBATCH -t 48:00:00 # Time for running job #길게 10일넘게 잡음
#SBATCH -o ./shell_output/output_%A_%a.output
#SBATCH -e ./shell_output/error_%A_%a.error
#SBATCH --ntasks=8
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=4GB
#SBATCH --gpus=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2
#SBATCH --array=0-7
```

(where I didn't use `--gpus-per-task`) I thought that since `--gpu` is specified as opposed to `--gpus-per-task`, the slum would allocate seperate cpus (as specified by `--cpus-per-task`), but share a single GPU. However, this is not the case and each task gets one GPU. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance for anyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

You can just run multiple tasks in a single shell file.
For instance, in your settings,

write train_slurm.sh files as: (I removed "#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=4GB")

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name parallel_finetune  
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --nodelist=node3 #used node4
#SBATCH -t 48:00:00 # Time for running job 
#SBATCH -o ./shell_output/output_%A_%a.output
#SBATCH -e ./shell_output/error_%A_%a.error
#SBATCH --ntasks=8
#SBATCH --gpus=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2
#SBATCH --array=0-7

sh train.sh | tee -a mylog
```

and write train.sh files as:

```
python train1.py &&
python train2.py &&
...
python train8.py &&
```

Honestly, this is not exactly what you wanted, I think it would work.